# Distriqt Share Invalid Input

Tags: distriqt

When adding the Distriqt Share ANE to my app via Flash Pro CC 2015 I get an Invalid input error and the app will not publish.

This is simply adding the ANE to the Library Paths list, no import or AS3 code is added.

If I remove the ANE, the app published fine. I have checked that the dev key is correct and compatible with the Share ANE.

Would anyone have any idea why this is happening and what can be done to fix it?

Thanks,

Mark

[image]

Comment: What version of AIR are you using?

Comment: Ah! I am using 20.0.0.206 (Beta)

If I revert back to 20.0.0.196 the issue disappears which is fine for me. 

Perhaps 20.0.0.206 includes an upcoming element you need to be aware of?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and found you need to include the iOS sdk when compiling to get past in invalid input error.

Instructions here: http://airnativeextensions.com/knowledgebase/tutorial/1#ios